# The connection with a cell with logical values is confused

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I put checkboxes to all residents, the connection with the cell with logical values is confused, when the <kbd>Next</kbd> button is pressed.

```
Sub Del_Row()
  Rows(ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Delete
  Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 11).Activate
 
  n = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count
  ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n).Delete
  ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 1).Delete
  ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 2).Delete
  ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 3).Delete
End Sub
 
 Sub Copy_Row()
   Dim rw As Long
   rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   Rows(rw).Copy
   Rows(rw + 1).Insert xlDown
   Rows(rw).Cells(1).Resize(2).DataSeries , xlChronological, xlMonth
   Range("K" & rw + 1 & ":AQ" & rw + 1).ClearContents
   n = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count
    
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n).LinkedCell = "CW" & rw + 1
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 1).LinkedCell = "CU" & rw + 1
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 2).LinkedCell = "CS" & rw + 1
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(n - 3).LinkedCell = "CQ" & rw + 1
        

   Range("K" & rw + 1).Activate
End Sub
```

It turned out that the cells are confused.

Comment: Please do not include links to your google drive in your question.

Comment: @braX, Without attaching a link to the file, it is impossible to explain what I need.

Comment: What do you mean by the cells are confused?  Is your code looking at the correct sheet - `Activesheet` is whichever sheet is active and could change when the code is running, `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` is always Sheet1 in the workbook containing the code.  As @braX said regarding google drive.  I can't connect to it from here either.  Also this question will still be here in 10 years time, but the link will more than likely be broken at that point so it wouldn't help people in the future with similar problems.

Comment: You can use words, nicely formatted text lists [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) and pictures to explain your problem (please, don't use pictures to show data if you want people to copy and test it).